# Update database table from DataGridView using DataAdapter

Tags: vb.net, oracle

**EDIT: This was resolved by querying the table directly rather than by using a stored procedure and ref cursor.**

I have a form which only contains a DataGridView `dgvDetail`. This is the form class code:

```
Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Public Class FRM_EditDetail

    Dim DataAdapter As New OracleDataAdapter
    Dim CommandBuilder As New OracleCommandBuilder(DataAdapter)
    Dim Connection As New OracleConnection(connectionString)
    Dim Command As OracleCommand = Connection.CreateCommand()

    Private Sub FRM_EditDetail_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Connection.Open()
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Command.CommandText = "SV_PACKAGE.GetDetail"
        Command.Parameters.Add("P_CURSOR", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        DataAdapter.SelectCommand = Command
        DataAdapter.Fill(dsData, "Detail")
        dsData.Tables("Detail").PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dsData.Tables("Detail").Columns("ID")}
        dgvNHHDetail.DataSource = dsData.Tables("Detail")

    End Sub

    Private Sub FRM_EditDetail_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

        CommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
        DataAdapter.Update(dsData, "Detail")
        Connection.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

I want the user to open the form, change the data, and when they close the form the changes are passed into the database table.

The `Load` event works correctly in so far as `dgvDetail` is populated from the database table correctly. I get no error on the `dsData.Tables("Detail").PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dsData.Tables("Detail").Columns("ID")}` line, and my database table has a primary key of the same column.

However the `FormClosing` event triggers, get the `Dynamic SQL generation failed. No key information found`.

What am I doing wrong with assigning a primary key (or something else)?

Comment: In order to use a command builder, your query must involve a single table and retrieve the primary key for that table. Does your query qualify? If so, try setting the `MissingSchemaAction` property of your data adapter to `AddWithKey` and don't bother setting the `PrimaryKey` of your `DataTable` explicitly.  If not, you can't use a command builder and will have to create the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` yourself.

Comment: My query is simply `SELECT * FROM Detail` and the table `Detail` does have a primary key. However, I get at it via a stored procedure and ref_cursor. Would this likely be the problem? I added `DataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey` but same result.

Comment: Yep. Using a ref cursor doesn't pass any primary key information, querying the table directly works.